# How to Git pull from master on a dev branch if you had set a different upstream?

Tags: git, version-control

I was on the master branch at first. Then, I have created a new branch `newBranch` and switched into it. Then I commited my changes and pushed.

Now, my problem is how to pull changes from `master`. I did `git fetch` and that seemed to work fine, but when I did `git status` it only showed changes from my `newBranch`. I want to be able to pull changes from `master` into `newBranch`.

Here are the commands I typed into the terminal:

```
$ git branch -a

* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master


$ git fetch

$ git pull

$ git switch -b newBranch

$ git branch -a

  master
* newBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master 


$ git add *

$ git commit -m "First commit"

$ git push --set-upstream origin newBranch

$ git fetch origin master
From git.domain.com:dev-folder
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD


$ git status   # This command doesn't show changes from master ???
On branch newBranch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/newBranch'.
```

Comment: `git fetch origin master` only fetches the changes. You'll need to merge it into `newBranch` to see those changes.

Comment: Is your branch ahead of master?

Comment: My branch is not ahead but that commit I made was pushed only to my branch hence those changes are not in `master`

Comment: It must be ahead of master since it was branched of master and a commit was added?

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what `ahead` means but when I was on master I did `git fetch` and `git pull` first, then I made made changes in the code and then I created and switched into the new branch. After that I commited and pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) command downloads the commits (and their associated objects) from a remote repository into your own, but it doesn't *merge* them into the current branch. That's what the [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) command is for:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

In your case, you can merge the commits from `origin/master` into your local `newBranch` branch with:

```sh
git pull origin master
```

which is the equivalent of running `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/master`.

If you prefer to *rebase* your local commits on top of `origin/master`, you can tell `git pull` to do a rebase instead of merge with:

```sh
git pull --rebase origin master
```

which, again, is the equivalent of running `git fetch origin` and `git rebase origin/master`.